# Cannot read property OnSnapshot of undefined

Tags: javascript, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-authentication

```
componentDidMount() { 
   this.authListener = auth.onAuthStateChanged( async userAuth => {
    if(userAuth){
        const userRef = await handleUserProfile(userAuth); userRef.onSnapshot(snapshot=>{
             this.setState({ currentUser:{ id:snapshot.id, ...snapshot.data() } }) }) } this.setState({ ...initialState })
     }); 
    }
```

Comment: Please share the complete code. We can't see where is handleUserProfile defined.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your function `handleUserProfile` is not returning the `userRef` so you get that error. It would be great to provide more that to help you more with this. Maybe the code of that function `handleUserProfile`.

Can you try to updated your `handleUserProfile` function to:

```js
export const handleUserProfile = async ({ userAuth, additionalData = {} }) => {
  if (!userAuth) {
    console.warn("No userAuth provided!");
    return;
  }

  const { uid } = userAuth;
  const userRef = firestore.doc(`users/${uid}`);
  const snapshot = await userRef.get();

  if (!snapshot.exists) {
    const { displayName, email } = userAuth;
    const timestamp = new Date();
    try {
      await userRef.set({
        displayName,
        email,
        createdDate: timestamp,
        ...additionalData,
      });
    } catch (err) {
      console.warn(err);
    }
  }

  return userRef;
};
```

If you are getting the log `No userAuth provided!` you are not sending a `userAuth` to it.

Comment: export const handleUserProfile = async ({ userAuth, additionalData }) => {
  if (!userAuth) return;
  const { uid } = userAuth;

  const userRef = firestore.doc(`users/${uid}`);
  const snapshot = await userRef.get();

  if (!snapshot.exists) {
    const { displayName, email } = userAuth;
    const timestamp = new Date();
    
    try {
      await userRef.set({
        displayName,
        email,
        createdDate: timestamp,
   
        ...additionalData
      });
    } catch(err) {
      // console.log(err);
    }
  }
  return userRef;
};

Comment: I have updated the answer. Can you try it out.

Comment: Change this part to `const userRef = await handleUserProfile({userAuth})`. In the function you accept an object but you send into it directly the `userAuth`. So chnage it to call like `({userAuth})`